# Shredding data from XML, Importing into Relational Tables (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xquery, relational

I have looked everywhere for help on this.

I'm new to all this and I'm finding it hard to understand all the documentation on it.

Say I have this XML:

```
<footballteams>
  <team manager="Benitez">
    <name>Liverpool</name>
    <ground>Anfield</ground>
  </team>
  <team manager="Mourinho">
    <name>Chelsea</name>
    <ground>Stamford Bridge</ground>
  </team>
  <team manager="Wenger">
    <name>Arsenal</name>
    <ground>Highbury</ground>
  </team>
</footballteams>
```

I want to take the data from this and load it into a relational table called footballteams(name,manager,ground).

I would like to do this in SQL Server 2008, and from what I have read everywhere a useful method to do this is .nodes() method, but I just can't understand how to use it.

Comment: Good question, and +1 for putting Liverpool at the top :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<footballteams>
  <team manager="Benitez">
    <name>Liverpool</name>
    <ground>Anfield</ground>
  </team>
  <team manager="Mourinho">
    <name>Chelsea</name>
    <ground>Stamford Bridge</ground>
  </team>
  <team manager="Wenger">
    <name>Arsenal</name>
    <ground>Highbury</ground>
  </team>
</footballteams>'


SELECT
    TeamName = Foot.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    Manager = Foot.value('(@manager)', 'varchar(100)'),
    Ground = Foot.value('(ground)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/footballteams/team') AS Tbl(Foot)
```

Basically, the call to `.nodes()` create a pseudo "table" called `Tbl` with a single XML column called `Foot` that will contain each `<team>` XML node as its value.

Then, you can select from that pseudo table and extract the individual values of XML attributes (`@manager`) and elements (`name`, `ground`) from that `<team>` XML snippet, and convert those to a T-SQL data value of a type of your chosing.

To insert those values into your table - just use an `INSERT` statement based on this:

```
;WITH ShreddedData AS
( 
  SELECT
    TeamName = Foot.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    Manager = Foot.value('(@manager)', 'varchar(100)'),
    Ground = Foot.value('(ground)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
  FROM
    @input.nodes('/footballteams/team') AS Tbl(Foot)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.FootballTeams(Name, Manager, Ground)
   SELECT TeamName, Manager, Ground
   FROM ShreddedData
```

Comment: Fantastic answer Marc (a fellow Scot into the bargain ;) )
I have a couple of questions if you don't mind...

1) I'm in a position where I will be doing this for multiple documents which shall have different structures. I am aiming to write an application in Java using JDBC to shred these various XML's into tables. How should I go about this?

2) Are there any advantages to be gained from Hybrid shredding?

Comment: (1) depends on whether you just want to load these XML documents into SQL Server and shred them there - or shred them beforehand, in Java, and insert the relational results - whatever is easier for you. (2) explain *hybrid* shredding - what do you mean by that?

Comment: From what I understand it is where some XML is stored in its native form, while some is 'shredded'. Thanks for your answer again Marc

Comment: @user1320771: guess it depends on whether you'll ever need that original XML back - for whatever reason. If so: you can totally store that XML into a SQL Server XML column and retrieve it later. Otherwise, I don't see any benefit in storing the XML alongside the relational data - you can always create an XML representation of your relational data if needed

Answer (score 0):

With simple XML you can use the XML adaptor in SSIS. It automatically creates an XSD. No programming needed. If the XML is more complex use www.eXtractor.ONE. A very generic method that handles every type of XML.